# Conque SML backspace

Tags: vim, sml

I have a problem with SML while running it in vim with conque. If I run the interpreter from the terminal then everything is ok. If I will run it using Conque it will be ok except for the fact that if I use the cursor it will write "^[[C" or "^[[A" or so on. ("^H" for backspace). What can I do?

Comment: Conque "works" but it has too many limitations and glitches and corner cases. Use a proper shell instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably talking about SML/NJ, in which case the REPL famously lacks readline support (why?  I really don't know).  I'm guessing those funny keystrokes you're seeing generated are the result of simulated arrow keypresses and such.

Most people irritated by the lack of readline support in SML/NJ use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/).  Perhaps you can find a way to make this work with your chosen environment.