# How to add readline support in polyml interpreter?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sml, ml, polyml

I found that `polyml` is the implementation of ML that can be easily installed on Ubuntu *(named polyml in repository and can be executed with `poly`)*. I am following the [A Gentle Introduction to ML](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/) by Andrew Cumming. After few minutes of experiment with `polyml` interpreter I found that it does not supports readline *(pressing arrow up key produces a **^[[A**)*.

This doesn't seems to be normal for an interpreter. This should only happen if I have no readline installed, but my Python interpreter doesn't behaves so.

Comment: sml/nj should also be available as the package "smlnj" under ubuntu as with mlton (though "only" a whole program compilor).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to add readline support to a terminal program that does not natively support it, is to call the program using `rlwrap`. You can install the package of the same name through several package managers. Pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> in the examples below:

```
$ poly
Poly/ML 5.7.1 Release
- ^[[A
```

You can run it like this:

```
$ rlwrap poly
Poly/ML 5.7.1 Release
- stuff I typed from last session;
```

Or you can add an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or similar:

```
alias poly='rlwrap poly'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following two QA answers your question, though for sml/nj. It should not be any different for polyml

- [Conque SML backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100914/conque-sml-backspace/13148731#13148731)
- [How to 'fix' the SML/NJ interactive system to use Arrow Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911861/how-to-fix-the-sml-nj-interactive-system-to-use-arrow-keys/1911886#1911886)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Standard ML and Poly/ML you should also take a look at Isabelle/ML.  Isabelle is mainly targeted as theorem proving environment, but can be used as ML system as well -- if you don't mind 300 MB download and 600-800 MB disk footprint to get a full IDE.

ML snippets can be compiled and evaluated on the spot, by embedding them into Isabelle theory source like this:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin

ML {*
  fun f x = x + 1
*}

end
```

In Isabelle/jEdit this gives tooltips about inferrred types etc. -- a bit more than just `readline` but useful for learning SML.